# Discord bot running locally but not on Azure

Tags: python, azure, discord, discord.py, pycord

I have started working on a discord bot which works fine if I run it on my machine, but when I push it to Azure it claims the app is running yet the bot is offline

`

```
import discord

bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.command(name='whereami', help='print the current server name/id')
async def whereami(ctx):

    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.name}, you are currently in {ctx.guild.name} ({ctx.guild.id}).')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"We have logged in as {bot.user}")

@bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[guild ID])
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.respond("Hello!")

bot.run("Token")
```

`

So far I've tried messing with the Azure settings, I made sure it was set to always on

Comment: Could you update the post with more details about how you deployed to Azure? What service did you deploy it to? Did you use Azure CLI or Portal?

Comment: I created an azure app service and deployed it from my github

Answer (score -1):

Im assuming that you already installed all required libraries in azure, if it runs on your machine perfectly fine it most likely would be on azure’s end, i would recommend you try repelit ive hosted plenty of discord bots there no problem and very cheap, you can also go the vps route but those tend to be a bit more expensive. But if you want to stay with azure make sure all libraries and dependencies are there and check your settings. If it gives you error would help if you let us know what that error says.

Comment: No. Do not host bots on replit. This isn't what the platform is made for, and abusing it to run bots brings dozens of issues along with it. There's questions on SO (& in the discord.py help server) on a daily basis about errors & other problems caused by replit. **There are no free hosts**, a VPS is the way to go.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if I installed them correctly, I was under the assumption that it's like Heroku where I push my code and it should work fine automatically

Comment: @Nephalem no, you still have to install any packages you want to use. However, you should get a clear error telling you that some packages aren't installed.

Comment: Pretty sure replit doesn’t mind hosting discord bots as they have even published docs on how to do it. https://docs.replit.com/tutorials/build-basic-discord-bot-python